# Temporarily override Theme CSS in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages, themes

I have a MasterPage that is two column layout, left column menu, right column content. The whole page is XHTML/Divs/CSS layout.  So the columns are div's with CSS applied to size them.

For one page, a grid page, I want only one column (the content column) to be 100% width for maximum viewing area.

How can I use the same masterpage and the same theme on this one off exception page?

Creating a whole new masterpage and adding a new CSS property to the theme just for this one page seems like overkill.  Is there a way to override the content div's CSS width property on just this page?  I'm not an expert in CSS but I thought there was a way to do this.

I do have some reservations about letting the client side do overriding though; for compatibility reasons.  I would prefer a server side override.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the way to solve this painlessly is to add another content region that acts as a one column.  That div can have the style that has 100% width.  I'll post with results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked like a charm.  Solution to this is to add another region to the masterpage with a new div that has the 100% width CSS assigned to it.  Also create a new style entry in your CSS file.  On the content page put the content you want to be 100% width in the region that has the style for 100% and not in the one that corresponds with the two column layout.

After that it's just a matter setting the content page to either use the masterpage content of the content page content.

MasterPage:

```
<!-- start page -->
<div id="page">
    <!-- start content -->
     <div id="contentOneColumn" >
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderContentOneColumn" runat="server">
      <!-- content that needs 100% width, one column -->
     </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
     </div>     
    <div id="content" >
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderContent" runat="server">
        <!-- content that works with two column -->
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

CSS:

```
/* Content */

content {
    float: right;
    width: 600px;
}

/* ContentOneColumn */
contentOneColumn {
    float:none;
    width: 850px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give each page a distinct CSS class in code, and target that class in your CSS. Here is a stupid-simple way to accomplish it:

Create your own MasterPage class:

```
class MyMasterPage : MasterPage
{
    public string BodyClass {get;set;}
}
```

In your Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Inherits="MyNamespace.MyMasterPage" %>
...
<body class="<% =this.BodyClass %>">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ... />
</body>
...
```

And in the codebehind of your page:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((MyMasterPage)Master).BodyClass = "specialpage";
}
```

And in your CSS class:

```
.specialpage .mainColumn {width:100%;}
.specialpage .otherColumn {display:none;}
```

Comment: Interesting.  However I'd have to change all of the pages to accommodate an exception. I don't have any requirements beyond this page to apply a different style to a shared div based on page. Gave me an idea though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to:

```
#content {
    /* Some styles */
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I take that this is how you override on the client?

Answer (score 0):

Use OnPreRenderComplete event, like this:

```
protected override void OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRenderComplete(e);
        rfv_login.CssClass = "ValidatorReset";
        rfv_pwd.CssClass = "ValidatorReset";
    }
```